# How to list all issues of a github repository with all assignees

Tags: github, github-cli

I use `gh` command to list and print all issues to a CSV file, but I can't get the all assignees also.

The complete command I use:

```bash
gh issue list --limit 1000 --state all | tr '\t' ',' > issues.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the default output contains comma-separated labels and one issue can have more than one label, your approach (converting all tabs to commas) can result in a malformed CSV output. To fix just that, you could use a CSV-aware tool such as [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv):

```bash
gh issue list --state all | xsv fmt -d '\t' > issues.csv
```

This properly quotes fields containing a comma.

Now, to get assignees as well, you can use the `--json` flag that lets you select which fields you want in the response, and `--jq` to massage the JSON response into CSV format.

For example, to get number, state, title, timestamp of the last update, labels, and assignees:

```bash
gh issue list --state all \
    --json number,state,title,labels,updatedAt,assignees \
    --jq '
        map([
            .number,
            .state,
            .title,
            .updatedAt,
            (.labels | map(.name) | join(",")),
            (.assignees | map(.login) | join(","))
        ])[]
        | @csv
    '
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of issues, need to use -L  to get more than 30 issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).